# Any acyclic complex of vector space over a field is split exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

So how to prove there exists a split map, i.e. a map s s.t. d=dsd, where d is the differential. What I know is there exists some decomposition of a vector space, but I still can not find such a map s.

Comment: Hint: Write your complex as a direct sum of complexes of the form $\cdots \to 0 \to 0 \to A \overset{\operatorname{id}}{\to} A \to 0 \to 0 \to \cdots$. (Here you will need $k$ to be a field.) Show that if some complexes have a split map, then so does their direct sum.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I am sorry, I still do not get the point? So specifically how should I construct the split map?

Comment: Actually, my hint was overkill. You need to construct, for each $n$, a linear map $s : C_n \to C_{n+1}$ such that $d = dsd$. These maps $s$ for different $n$'s are completely independent (the total $s$ does not have to be a morphism of chain complexes), so it is sufficient to consider one $n$. Now it remains to prove the following linear-algebraic fact: If $A$ and $B$ are two vector spaces and $d : A \to B$ is any linear map, then there exists a linear map $s : B \to A$ satisfying $d = dsd$. (This is called a *generalized inverse* of $d$; see ...

Comment: ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse .) I will leave that proof to you.